# Can my app be distributed through the MacOS App Store (struggling with Sandbox)?

Tags: swift, macos, app-store, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I'm new to MacOS app development, and just getting around to hopefully releasing an app. I have two options - the Mac App store or do it through my website.

I would have preferred to do via the App Store but realized it has a "sandbox" requirement, and I'm flummoxed on what I should do.

My app requires heavy file/folder access. Some of the basic requirements are

- ability to open and save files
- ability to create folders (without prompting, as part of a process run)
- ability for a backend process to access those files and run on it (e.g., if I added a markdown file to the app, and then run pandoc on it)

I can live with a user giving access to a base folder (and its subfolders) as kind of the app folder and I can work inside it. But being able to invoke a command-line tool installed on the mac, to run on those files, is paramount.

Can I do this at all? Or do I need to go outside the app store? I do not need access to system files etc and my app does absolutely nothing with any file except the ones within a project folder chosen by the user.

Any pointers to more recent documentation greatly appreciated. Kind of lost.

Comment: You are not allowed to create a folder without user's consent.  The only place where you are allowed to do it is within the sandbox folder that is assigned to your application.  Or your application would be DOA at review's hand.

Comment: @ElTomato isn't the app scope bookmark the way to do it? I'm trying to understand it further but it may be possible - just that I'm struggling as I'm new to all this.

Comment: Nope, it is not.